# Executar método em todas Activitys de acordo com um intervalo

Tags: android

Preciso que seja executado um método a cada 20 segundos, este método tem uma condição, se ela for falsa ele enviará um AlertDialog. Mas este método deve ser executado independente da Activity que está em primeiro plano, como fazer?

O método deve ser executado somente se o aplicativo estiver em primeiro plano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer que o contador de 20 segundos seja reiniciado a cada mudança de tela, então faça as atividades estenderem uma AtividadeBase, em cujo método onCreate() é iniciado o thread contador de 20 segundos (somente se savedInstanceState == null, claro, para evitar reiniciar o contador em caso de rotação da tela). Atingidos os 20 segundos, ele chama o AlertDialog através de um Handler.

Porém, se você quer que o contador seja global para o aplicativo, de forma que o usuário fique 10 segundos em uma tela e quando trocar de tela faltem somente 10 segundos para aparecer o AlertDialog, faça assim: AtividadeBase deve registrar um broadcast receiver em onResume() e "desregistrá-lo" em onPause(). Inicie um thread contador em uma classe separada e, quando o contador acabar, lance um broadcast, que a atividade atualmente em primeiro plano estará pronta para receber.